# How do I give an mpsc Receiver to a thread?

Tags: websocket, rust, client

I am trying to give the `mpsc::Receiver` object of a channel to a thread, it will only be called by a websocket client structure.

I've messed around with lifetimes, arcs, mutexes and I don't have enough knowledge about Rust to get it to work appropriately.

Thanks for any help you can give.

```
extern crate ws;
use ws::util::Token;
use ws::{connect, Handler, Handshake, Message, Result};
use std::sync::mpsc::{Receiver, SyncSender, sync_channel};
use std::thread;

fn main() {
    let (tx1, rx1) = sync_channel(100);
    let (tx2, rx2) = sync_channel(100);

    // set up rx2 and tx1

    let client = Client::new_thread(rx1, tx2);

    client.join().unwrap();
}


pub struct Client {
    pub out: ws::Sender,
    tx: SyncSender<Message>,
    rx: Receiver<Message>,
}

impl Client {
    pub fn new_thread(rx: Receiver<Message>, tx: SyncSender<Message>) -> thread::JoinHandle<()> {
        thread::spawn(move || {
            connect("ws://localhost:8000/ws/server/main", |out| Client {
                out,
                tx: tx.clone(),
                rx: rx,
            }).unwrap()
        })
    }
}

impl Handler for Client {
    fn on_open(&mut self, _: Handshake) -> Result<()> {
        self.out.timeout(250, Token(1))
    }
    fn on_message(&mut self, msg: Message) -> Result<()> {
        self.tx.send(msg).unwrap();
        Ok(())
    }
    fn on_timeout(&mut self, event: Token) -> Result<()> {
        //let msg = self.rx.recv()
        //self.out.send(msg)
        self.out.timeout(250, event)
    }
}
```

```
error[E0507]: cannot move out of captured outer variable in an `FnMut` closure                                                                         
  --> src/main.rs:31:21                                                                                                                                
   |                                                                                                                                                   
26 |     pub fn new_thread(rx: Receiver<Message>, tx: SyncSender<Message>) -> thread::JoinHandle<()> {                                                 
   |                       -- captured outer variable                                                                                                  
...                                                                                                                                                    
31 |                 rx: rx,                                                                                                                           
   |                     ^^ cannot move out of captured outer variable in an `FnMut` closure
```